# Media Query is not working in mobile gmail app

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating one html template for Gmail app. In I have added one image which should come 60% on the desktop view and 100% for mobile gmail app view.

This is img tag width 60%:

```
<div>
    <img src="show.jpg" alt="Show your skills" class="mob-img" border="0" 
    style="outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
    width:60%;" />
</div>
```

in media query I made it 100%. But it is not working in gmail app.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .mob-img {
        width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
```

I am not getting why this is not working in gmail app. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Issue is Gmail strip out css classes from html elements. You can experience this with the gmail on desktop.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is: Gmail App isn't a "screen" media.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .mob-img {
    width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

This solution works for me.

**EDIT:** Gmail ignores other media queries. Move the media query that is relevant to Gmail App to highest point possible.

Answer (score 2):

add media query    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

i things you can try this one it's working fine https://jsfiddle.net/oa5bco0s/

Comment: Thanks for reply. but this is not working in gmail mobile app.

Comment: in mobile app only one layout fallow i thing ,  why you have use multiple layout .

Answer (score 1):

add the meta on your html header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: then change      "only screen"    to     "screen"

Comment: by changing only screen to screnn also not working.I am getting problem only in gmail mobile app and in other places it is working fine.